# How to avoid double page numbering

Tags: page-numbering

I am trying to have the page numbers in my file appear on the top right hand corner of the page, and am using the fancyhdr package to do this. However, the automatic page numbering still puts an additional page number on the bottom of my pages. How can I remove the bottom numbers, while keeping my headers?

```
\documentclass[psamsfonts]{amsart}

%-------Packages---------
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[all,arc]{xy}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%--------Theorem Environments--------
%theoremstyle{plain} --- default
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{quest}[thm]{Question}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{defns}[thm]{Definitions}
\newtheorem{fact}[thm]{Fact}
\newtheorem{facts}[thm]{Facts}
\newtheorem{con}[thm]{Construction}
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{exmps}[thm]{Examples}
\newtheorem{notn}[thm]{Notation}
\newtheorem{notns}[thm]{Notations}
\newtheorem{addm}[thm]{Addendum}
\newtheorem{exer}[thm]{Exercise}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{rems}[thm]{Remarks}
\newtheorem{warn}[thm]{Warning}
\newtheorem{sch}[thm]{Scholium}

\newcommand{\legendre}[2]{\genfrac{(}{)}{}{}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}

\makeatletter
\let\c@equation\c@thm
\makeatother
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

%--------Meta Data: Fill in your info--------

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\chead{\textsc{Sample Text}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\cfoot{}` to make an empty foot?

Comment: The `psamsfonts` option is obsolete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\cfoot{}` to make an empty foot.